# Active Directory reverse DNS zone for multiple subnets

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, reverse-dns

Hi have an Active Directory domain spanning multiple subnets, for example:

- 192.168.1.0/24 is the main site;
- 192.168.10.0/24, 192.168.11.0/24, etc. are branch offices.

Actually, the (AD integrated) DNS is configured to have a single reverse IPv4 zone for the main site subnet only (1.168.192.in-addr.arpa); this means the remote branch's PCs, which do not have a proper reverse zone, can not register their reverse IP address.

Now I would like to create a "super-zone" to catch any 168.192.in-addr.arpa reverse IP, while continuing to use 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa for the main office's PCs.

I understand that the reverse operation (breaking a super-zone in multiple smaller zones) can [lead to various problems and it is discouraged](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2017/01/09/the-case-of-the-vanishing-static-reverse-dns-records/); however, I am really trying to **avoid** creating multiple smaller reverse zones.

So: is it ok to create a new large zone for any 192.168.x.0/24 networks (minus the 192.168.1.x/24 network) or I risk some unexpected problems?

Comment: At the end of the day, AD doesn't use reverse lookup zones or PTR records so whichever way you configure them you're not going to break AD. If you have applications that utilize PTR records then you may have issues with those, but AD will be unaffected by either design choice.

Comment: Sure, but I would like to avoid *any* reverse-dns related problem. When creating a larger zone, no delegation is automatically created for the smaller one. This *should* means that the problem described in the link I gave does not happen, right?